# Python try except не работает?

Tags: python

Что-то я не пойму.... 
Что я делаю не так? 
Если данные получить не удаётся прога всё равно вываливается с ошибкой

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Спасибо.

```
def get_data(self):
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(self.current_url) as self.current_url:
            data = json.loads(self.current_url.read().decode())
    except:
        print('error')
```

Полный текст ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1230, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1276, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1225, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1004, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 944, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 915, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 914, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/msmolkin/YandexDisk/ws/ws3.py", line 307, in <module>
    window()
  File "C:/Users/msmolkin/YandexDisk/ws/ws3.py", line 298, in window
    win.get_weather()
  File "C:/Users/msmolkin/YandexDisk/ws/ws3.py", line 285, in get_weather
    with urllib.request.urlopen(self.current_url) as self.current_url:
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\msmolkin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Это вопрос здесь несколько раз повторялся. Причину, по которой всё же выбрасывает я понял, в мануале питона написано "Handlers only handle exceptions that occur in the corresponding try clause". Но вот как отловить это исключение, которое случилось не в этом блоке? Вроде и должно же быть просто, но чёткого рецепта не нахожу. except Exception as e: не помогает.

Comment: Я дописал ваш огрызок кода до более-менее запускаемого примера, запустил, и у меня вывелось 'error'. Так что если хотите, чтобы вам помогли - приведите более полный пример кода. Хотя бы класс целиком. Но как минимум вызывает удивление часть с 'as self.current_url'. Зачем вы записываете объект ответа в тот же атрибут, где у вас до этого лежал урл?

Answer (score 0):

Только сильно не смейтесь, пожалуйста

Проблема была в том, что было как-то так

```
class MainWindow():
....
def func(self):
    try:
        return 1/0
    except:
        print('error')
def func(self):
    return 1/0
```

MainWindow.func()

Comment: Совет! Если сделали try / except то всегда делайте и return снизу по коду. Что бы тот кто вызвал функцию однозначно получал результат. 
def func(self):
result = 0    
try:
        result 1/0
    except:
        print('error')
    return result