# Python не работает защищённый блок

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, break, try

Если в блоке `except` убрать `break` нужное сообщение печатается, но бесконечное число раз, в итоге программа зависает и на этом всё. Добавляя `break`, я ожидала, что после возникновения исключения программа выведет один раз 'Устройство ещё не подключено' и выйдет из цикла, однако она просто не видит блок `except` и редактор кода пишет, что он не достижим. Вот код, помогите исправить

```
def toggle_recording_state(self,instance):
    while True:
        try:
            if self.btn_record.text == 'Запись':
                self.btn_record.text = 'Стоп'
                sampling_frequency = 1024
                self.file_path = None
                self.edf_writer = pyedflib.EdfWriter('temp.edf',self.channels,file_type=pyedflib.FILETYPE_EDFPLUS)
                Clock.schedule_interval(self.save_data, 1 / sampling_frequency)
            else:
                # Остановить запись данных
                self.edf_writer.close()
                self.file_chooser.path = "~/"
                self.file_chooser.filters = [lambda folder, filename: filename.endswith('.edf')]
                self.file_chooser.popup()
                self.btn_record.text = "Запись"
                Clock.unschedule(self.save_data)
        except:
            print('Устройство ещё не подключено')
            break
```

Comment: Возможно поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1053741/python-try-except-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82

Comment: Как вариант: используйте return, вместо print и break, и выводите результат выполнения функции в консоль, из того места, откуда вы эту функцию вызываете.

Comment: И зависает, как я понимаю, у вас в блоке else?
Вам нужно либо что-то сделать со строчкой 'self.btn_record.text = "Запись"', либо явно выходить из метода return'ом, тогда у вас все будет отрабатывать нормально.

Comment: У вас вообще очень странный цикл. Если всё ок и исключений не возникает, то он у вас будет бегать туда-сюда между `if` и `else`, выполняя их поочерёдно и переключая кнопку туда-сюда. Разве эта функция не должна выполняться по нажатию на какую-то кнопку? Если да, то зачем там `while True`? Разберитесь сначала, какое поведение вы хотите получить от этого метода во всех возможных вариантах того, как сработает `if` и сработает ли `except`.

Comment: Какую библиотеку графического интерфейса используете? В принципе при использовании GUI не должно быть бесконечных циклов.

Comment: @insolor почему же? Я писал обработку спутниковых изображений с текущим прогрессом и все отлично получилось. Конечно же, не без использования потоков)

Comment: @tonysdev, про потоки — это важное уточнение. Но в данном случае, судя по тому, что все зависает — этот цикл запущен в основном потоке.

Answer (score 0):

Советую завести отдельную переменную в классе с именем `device`, тогда будет намного удобнее работать с самим устройством.

Вот реализация, которую я считаю правильной:

```
def toggle_recording_state(self, instance):
    if self.device.is_connected():
        if self.btn_record.text == "Запись":
            self.btn_record.text = "Стоп"

            self.file_path = None

            self.edf_writer = pyedflib.EdfWriter("temp.edf", self.channels, file_type=pyedflib.FILETYPE_EDFPLUS)

            sampling_frequency = 1024
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.save_data, 1 / sampling_frequency)
        elif self.btn_record.text == "Стоп":
            self.btn_record.text = "Запись"

            self.file_chooser.path = "~/"
            self.file_chooser.filters = [lambda folder, filename: filename.endswith(".edf")]
            self.file_chooser.popup()

            self.edf_writer.close()

            Clock.unschedule(self.save_data)
        else:
            # Обработать нестандартное поведение кнопки(или не обрабатывать:|)
            pass
    else:
        print('Устройство ещё не подключено')
```

Бесконечные циклы в gui не везде нужны, в данном случае не вижу необходимости в нем.

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите как создать переменную `device`, если подключение к устройству осуществляется выбором из списка `Dropdown`?

Comment: @Karina В первую очередь нужно создать класс `Device` или `Devices` и создать какую-то двустороннюю привязку к списку устройств(думаю, что список устройств вы получаете из какого-то модуля), а далее уже определиться с архитектурой, может, вы захотите там еще получать `CurrentDevice`(следовательно, правильно будет использовать имя для класса `Devices`, а внутри него будет уже ваш `Device` с именем `CurrentDevice`) и от него уже получать информацию о подключении.